# google documents list api

Tags: c#, .net

I've been following the below link to integrate my web application to google docs using .net.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

What I can't get working is to open / view a document once I have retrieved the list of docos. I've tried the example they have provided however it doesn't seem to work.

How can this be achieved? Ideally clicking on it should just open the document in the web browser.

Comment: Have you tried the [Google embedded viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) all what you need is the path to the file.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work..for any document it just opens up a html document with the following content....................................<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to Google Docs</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, dl,
  dt, dd, ol, ul, li, table, tr, td, form, object, embed,
  article, aside, canvas, command, details, fieldset,
  figcaption, figure, footer, group, header, hgroup, legend,
  mark, menu, meter, nav, output, progress, section, summary,
  time, audio, video {
  margin: 0;